# XAML - 2 buttons in one grid column

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have to put 2 buttons in this same row and column on grid
i don't want use margin or vertical position, but i want to their positions is:
on upper than second.

how to simply do that?
i did this by:

```
<button1 verticalAligment="top" />
<button2 verticalAligment="bottom" />
```

but how to do that better way?

Answer (score 2):

Try This.

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="AppsGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

                                    <telerik:GridViewColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="40" Cursor="Hand" Content="Edit" FontSize="14" Background="#FFF2F2F2" CornerRadius="3" verticalAligment="top"/>
                                                <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="50" Cursor="Hand" Content="Delete" FontSize="14" Background="#FFF2F2F2" CornerRadius="3" verticalAligment="bottom"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridViewColumn>
                                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Wrappanel as follows

```
<Wrappanel Orientation="Horizontal"><button1 HorizontalAlignment="Left"/><button2 HorizontalAlignment="Right" /></Wrappanel>
```